# Why would Windows Server 2012 not respond on ports above 6000?

Tags: networking, windows-server-2012, port, tcp, windows-firewall

This is a new question but similar to [this previous one](https://serverfault.com/questions/488999/server-2012-syn-no-acks-on-tcp-ports-higher-than-6000).

I've inherited the management of a Windows 2012 Server (not R2) and I'm unable to get a response from any ports above 6000. 
I have services on 8098, 41200 and 42222. Netstat shows they are listening.
There is no positive rejection. Client requests just timeout.

I've tried with the firewall off for all profiles and with rules to open all ports & applications etc
I've ensured NAP is disabled.
I've removed the Direct Access role that the customer had installed but didn't need and have removed the policies that this role installed.
I've done a Base Filtering Engine reset by removing the policy keys in the registry and then doing a "netsh advfirewall reset" followed by a reboot.

I haven't yet tried turning off the BFE service completely but I need to be on site to do that as I'll lose connection when the dependent Windows Firewall service stops.

I've spent hours and hours on this and cannot find the cause or any sensible suggestions for what else it could be.
I've seen other posts elsewhere about problems with ports above 6000 but they don't lead to anything useful.

Is there something specific about TCP ports > 6000 ?

Comment: Can you confirm that if you move these services to ports below 6000, eg 5996-9 then all works as expected?

Comment: I am unable to move them down as they are hard-coded in the 3rd party software. But I did set up some dummy IIS web sites below and above 6000 and got no responses from the ones above 6000.

Comment: I have an interesting update on this. I found that if I stop the Base Filtering Engine service (and thus its dependent Windows Firewall service, PolicyAgent and IKEEXT services) these ports start responding. Strangely, if I start them again, the ports still respond. If I reboot, they stop again. I tried stopping the dependent services one by one but that didn't help. A script with a quick stop/start of the BFE and Windows Firewall just after reboot is currently the work-around solution.

Comment: shot in the dark, but have you checked this article?
http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2008/10/29/port-exhaustion-and-you-or-why-the-netstat-tool-is-your-friend.aspx

Comment: Does this happen on a brand new clean install?
related: http://serverfault.com/questions/488999/server-2012-syn-no-acks-on-tcp-ports-higher-than-6000?rq=1

Comment: To @BlueCompute, thanks but this is a customer's server we have inherited. I can't do a fresh install. I believe their previous IT guy installed every server role he could without really understanding what he was doing. We are unraveling a bit of a mess on site. That related link was actually the reason I came to this site originally. The description of the problem is identical but there's no final conclusion unfortunately. So I asked the question again.

Comment: To @Goatmale, thanks I have looked into this possibility before and even tried the registry change to extend dynamic ports. However now that I can make it work by restarting the BFE after boot up, I'm looking into different possibilities.

Comment: Do a fresh install on a different server... like a 'test environment' you could call it....

Comment: Is there a firewall or AV (Symantec crap blocks ports) running on the server or hyper-visor?

Comment: No 3rd party firewall at all. I would have gone for that as culprit #1 if there was :-)

Comment: Just to update the status here, I have written a simple script to restart the BFE service and dependencies a couple of mins after Windows comes up. While not a permanent solution, it has held fine as a workaround for the past 4 weeks.

Comment: DirectAccess role? Single NIC? I had a similar issue, I has a process listening on all interfaces but I could only connect using loopback, not IP (syn timeout). Initial test would be to use Python (v2) to listen on all interfaces: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 5938` of course telnet to this using the IP worked.  I moved it next to the port I had issues with and it failed.  I found the cut off to be 6000.   In the case of your 8098 port run 
`Set-NetNatTransitionConfiguration –IPv4AddressPortPool @(“10.0.0.1, 6001-8097”, “10.0.0.1, 8099-47000”)` and reboot, changing the IP to be your IP.